# Configure Pin Swapping in Altium for a library component?

Tags: pcb, components, altium, library

I was wondering if someone knew if there was a way to configure pin swap groups on a library component in Altium, rather than from the schematic, so I didn't have to do it every time I put down a large memory or FPGA.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to enable pin-swapping on a component from the altium libraries that does not have pin swapping already available, you're going to have to edit the library.

Find the built-in library (It'll likely be an `*.IntLib`), break it down to a schematic and PCB library (`*.SchLib`, `*.PcbLib`), and make your changes to the `SchLib`. Then, instead of using the assembled `IntLib`, you just add the two separate libraries to any project that needs them.